# How to turn a indicator into a strategy?

Tags: pine-script

Im aware it needs to have `strategy("title", overlay=true)` at the beginning.

I have these conditions set up for a Long or Short Position:

```
LongSignal = not Short and (close>high[25]) and CP>BP and (close>LL2[25] and close>LL1[25]) and (low>LL2[25] and low>LL1[25])
ShortSignal = not Long and (close<high[25]) and CP<BP and (close<LL2[25] and close<LL1[25]) and (high<LL2[25] and high<LL1[25])
```

How would I make the strategy tester on TradingView recognize these Correctly, for right now I want it to enter a Long when my Long Signal label is plotted and then Sell and also take a short signal when Short Signal is Plotted.

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100, process_orders_on_close = true)


LongSignal = not Short and (close>high[25]) and CP>BP and (close>LL2[25] and close>LL1[25]) and (low>LL2[25] and low>LL1[25])
ShortSignal = not Long and (close<high[25]) and CP<BP and (close<LL2[25] and close<LL1[25]) and (high<LL2[25] and high<LL1[25])

if (LongSignal)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

if (ShortSignal)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```